# Why method is parameterized while type parameter is never used?

Tags: scala, scalatest

In ScalaTest there is a `org.scalatest.selenium.WebBrowser` trait which provides this method:

```
def executeScript[T](script: String, args: AnyRef*)(implicit driver: WebDriver): AnyRef =
    driver match {
      case executor: JavascriptExecutor => executor.executeScript(script, args.toArray : _*)
      case _ => throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Web driver " + driver.getClass.getName + " does not support javascript execution.")
    }
```

I am curious why this method is parameterized when the type parameter `T` is not used in implementation. Documentation does not say anything on this regard.

Could you clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Semmle](https://help.semmle.com/wiki/display/SCALA/Unused+type+parameter):

> An unused type parameter will have no effect and always be inferred to
>   `Nothing`.

It also provides the following recommendation:

> Unused type parameters have no effect on your program beyond confusing
>   the reader and cluttering up the definition... Remove the type
>   parameter if it is genuinely unused, or add a use if it is supposed to
>   be used.